# Power BI - Subtract values from same row

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following output from two tables.

```
Item#     Desc     Sales    Rank1    Company      Sales     Rank2     Rank Diff
1         Wigit1    500      1         ABC         15       32          31
2         Wigit2    300      2         XYZ         80       16          14
```

`Rank1` data is from `table A` and `Rank2` data is from `table B`.  Both tables are tied together with the `Item#`. I'm trying to correctly get the `Rank Diff` to calculate from `Rank2 - Rank1`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in Power Query with a simple merge and add a Custom Column with the arithmetic.  This can all be achieved using the menu and options, no code required. This is the same as in Excel, so here's a [walkthrough from Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/combine-data-from-multiple-data-sources-power-query-70cfe661-5a2a-4d9d-a4fe-586cc7878c7d) that goes through all the steps you might need. Once you start using Power Query you won't look back. Good Luck!

Comment: I was hoping I could figure out a correct way to structure a new measure or something.  I don't have Power Query.

Comment: If you have Power BI you have PowerQuery, it's the 'Transform Data; option on the Home Ribbon. What you want isn't really a measure, it's more of a column value if you have the data loaded you could add a computed column using DAX using 'New Column' on the Data Menu

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have excess to 'Transform Data'( Power Query new name), then simply go to modelling tab and create a new column

Rank_Diff= TableName[Rank2]-TableName[Rank1]